# Changing granularity of amCharts data

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, aggregate-functions, amcharts

I have built a serial chart using amCharts. The **workflow** is:

- The front end allows user to add trendlines one-by-one.
- For each trendline added, data is being fetched from a MySQL database (using PHP script) and returned to amCharts in JSON format.

**Desired feature:**
- The user should have the ability to choose a different granularity. MySQL DB has data for each minute. The user may choose to plot hourly average values, for example.

**Question:**
- Is it possible to do the aggregation AFTER the minute-wise data has been fetched from MySQL and returned in JSON format? Maybe some JavaScript function can aggregate the JSON data that is being returned by PHP/MySQL.

The reason I do NOT wish to do the aggregation in MySQL queries is to make the aggregation switches faster. For example, if the front-end JavaScript is aggregating the minute-wise MySQL data, switching from hourly-average to daily-average would NOT require to query the MYSQL DB again, as the minute-wise data is already available.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks
Pranav

Answer (score 0):

You just have to save Json result in variable then re-build JSON and pass this rebuild to amcharts. With that, you do aggregation with JS. The only disadvantage is that when user wants to see average trendline, you have to ask detailed to server...

**Example**
You have 10 different trendlines, each trendline has 4 granularity: day, month, year, century.

**First method**
If user asks 5 trendlines with granuarity year, you AJAX CALL to get json of 5 trendlines of day granuarity and then construct month, year ans century, by client-side, by using JS.

Then if user asks for 6 trenlines (and 5 that user has already aske dbefore), you have to make the JS enough smart in order to call only one trendline and add it to the 5 that you already get

**Second method**
Or you create complex mecanism that enrich trendline data preicsion as demand :
If user asks 5 trendlines with grabuarity month, you get month, then you can construct year and century but not day because it is not needed.

Then If user asks for 6 trendlines of granuarity years, then you have to make the function as smart that JSON receive will only contains 1 trendline of year granuarity and then build century for only this trendline because other trendlines are already available in JS.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, I do NOT understand the part where you said "you have to ask detailed to server... Or you create complex mecanism that enrich trendline data preicsion as demand"

Comment: @luvlogic does it responds to your question?